# Condição If em variavel

Tags: jquery, variáveis, if

Tenho uma variável chamada *LastClass*, ela pode ter o valor de *headerSortDown* ou *headerSortUp*. Estou resgatando-a de uma coluna ordenada.

Quero transferir essa variável para um `<a href>` porém queria mudar o texto dela.

Por exemplo ao invés de ficar `href="produto=headerSortDown"` ficar `href="produto=Down"`.

Essa variável muda dinamicamente conforme o usuário ordena a coluna DESC ou ASC. Já consigo resgatar dinamicamente isso.

Tem como eu usar um `if` ou algo assim para poder troca o nome do valor da variável e assim colocar no `href`?

Comment: Funcionou @Sergio, Obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Falta alguma informação para poder dar uma resposta bem adaptada ao seu problema mas, partindo do princípio que só tem duas possibilidades e assumindo que já tem a variável que refere se é `headerSortDown` ou `headerSortUp`, a lógica pode ser assim:

```
var url = LastClass == 'headerSortDown' ? 'produto=Down' : 'produto=Up';
$('a').attr("href", url);
```

Sugiro mudar essa variável para `lastClass` com letra pequena só por que é prática comum dar letra grande para Classes.

Comment: Ele disse que a variável se chama LastClass

Comment: @LcSalazar ok, obrigado, mudei o nome. A lógica é a mesma.

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que o valor `headerSortDown` vire `Down`, e o valor `headerSortUp` vire `Up`, pode usar a função `.replace()` do Javascript para remover o prefixo de qualquer que seja o valor:

```
LastClass = LastClass.replace("headerSort", "");
```